# probleme of SLIM package in google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

please, I want to use the Sparse LInear Method (SLIM) package in my project, firstly I installed the package by this command:

`pip install SLIM`

when I execute my script I have this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SLIM'`

how can I resolve this problem?  and thank you

Comment: Apparently, the `slim` you install with `pip` is ["A Web framework provides instant restful api for your database"](https://pypi.org/project/slim/). There's [another lib called SLIM](https://github.com/KarypisLab/SLIM) on GitHub

Comment: yes, I used this SLIM package <https://github.com/KarypisLab/SLIM>
but it doesn't support pip installation !!!
Is there an alternative to this package to install on google Colab?

Comment: I think it should be possible to build everything as specified [in the README](https://github.com/KarypisLab/SLIM#downloading-slim), since Colab has almost all capabilities of a normal computer, like internet access and a C++ toolchain

Comment: I don't know, what is the equivalent of all the commands written in the README to google Colab commands?

Comment: I think commands from the README should work in Colab `with no changes`. Just prefix all shell commands with a bang, like `!git clone ...`

Comment: when I run these lines I get the following results: 
 commands : !cd /lib/GKlib
!make config openmp=set
!make   .... results : /bin/bash: line 0: cd: /lib/GKlib: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'config'.  Stop.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
!cd ../../

Comment: The README says the correct command is `cd lib/GKlib`. `/lib/GKlib` is _not_ the same as `lib/GKlib`

Comment: I did not understand your answer correctly?
I wrote :
! cd / lib / GKlib
! make config openmp = set
! make
! cd ../../
what is that the error in this writing?

Comment: The README on GitHub says: `lib/GKlib`. You wrote: `/lib/GKlib`. These are _different paths_: one doesn't have a leading slash (`/`), and the other one does.

Comment: despite this, I got the same error:
`/ bin / bash: line 0: cd: lib / GKlib: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'config'. Stop.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`
i must mention that, when I executed this code:
`! sudo apt-get install build-essential
! sudo apt-get install cmake `
I got this message:
`Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded. `

Comment: IMO, you should [raise an issue on SLIM's GitHub](https://github.com/KarypisLab/SLIM/issues) and say that you're following their installation instructions to the tee, but getting such and such errors

Comment: I think the problem exists exactly here:
`! make config openmp = set
! make
! cd ../../`
the message is:
`make: *** No rule to make target 'config'. Stop.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that:

```
import slim
```

and not:

```
import SLIM
```

don't forget Python is case sensitive